# Need help with XPATH for src value of a specific Html img tag

Tags: c#, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am somewhat new to XPATH and understand most of the basics, but I am having some trouble with a particular query.

I am attempting to parse a Motley Fool page and return the source of the image for the caps score of a stock.

For example: if you look at the source for the page: http://caps.fool.com/Ticker/SLT.aspx I want the source for http://g.foolcdn.com/art/ratings/stars/trans/5stars-trans-lg.png

I only want what follows the src= if possible.

I am currently working with:

```
xpath = "//div[@class='subtle marginT']"
```

This however is returning nothing. I know it might be asking a lot, but if you feel like answering, I would also greatly appreciate a quick reasoning for the answer as I want to learn XCAP, not just get this query to work.

Comment: How are you programming? Javascript running in the browser? Something else?

Comment: @bmargulies Sorry, I am using C# and the HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-liner XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted attribute. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your URL this worked for me:

```
var imageNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='tickerStats']/tbody/tr/td/img");
string imageText = imageNode.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Basically just grabbing the closest element that has an id, then walking the tree down to where you want to be.

Alternatively this would work too and seems a little cleaner (since you don't really care about the DOM structure in the table itself as long as there is just one image):

```
var statsNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='tickerStats']");
var imageNode = statsNode.SelectSingleNode(".//img");
string imageText = imageNode.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks again buddy! Trying to wrap my head around xcap in short amount of time has been a bit challenging, but your help has gotten me going in the right direction and I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
//table[@id='tickerStats']/tbody/tr/td/img/@src
```

This selects any attribute named `src` of any element named `img` that is a child of a `td` that is a child of a `tr` that is a child of a `tbody` that is a child of any `table` in the document, that has an `id` attribute with value 'tickerStats'.

**If you need just the string value** of this attribute (assuming the above XPath expression selects a single attribute node), use:

```
string(//table[@id='tickerStats']/tbody/tr/td/img/@src)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I greatly appreciate you taking the time to write that up.